# How do I rewrite this RSS Reader using CURL instead of file_get_contents?

Tags: php, curl, rss

Admittedly, I'm a novice and know only enough to be dangerous.

The host server doesn't allow file_get_contents due to security concerns. How can I rewrite the code below using curl instead of file_get_contents?

This is for a rss reader on a jquery mobile site. The code is based on a tutorial I found here: [nets.tutplus.com/rssreader](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-build-an-rss-reader-with-jquery-mobile-2/comment-page-2/#comments)

```
<?php
$siteName = empty($_GET['siteName']) ? 'Website' : $_GET['siteName'];
$siteList = array(
'Website2',
'Website3',
'Website4',
'Website5',
'Website6',
);
// For security.
if ( !in_array($siteName, $siteList) ) {
$siteName = 'Website';
}
$location = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
$location .= urlencode("SELECT * FROM feed where url='http://feeds.feedburner.com/$siteName'");
$location .= "&format=json";
$rss = file_get_contents($location, true);
$rss = json_decode($rss);
?>
```

Edit: Would this work?

```
$location = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
$location .= urlencode("SELECT * FROM feed where url='http://feeds.feedburner.com/$siteName'");
$location .= "&format=json";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $location);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, trim($request)); 
$rss = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 

$rss = json_decode($rss);
```

Comment: If your hosting provider does not allow file_get_contents, they most certainly won't allow PHP cURL (which needs to be installed separately from PHP).

Comment: You may just be able to turn on file_get_contents with a php.ini file (search your provider for detail)

Comment: @RobotWoods I did that for our test server, but it looks like I'm not able to on the live server.

Comment: @MatthewJordan I don't think that's correct at all .. to use cURL you have to have a) libcurl, b) the curl php drivers.  The fopen wrappers are totally separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `CURLOPT_POST...` lines entirely.  `$request` is not set, and you don't need to make a post request in this instance where a GET request will do.  You may or may not need to use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` -- turn it on if curl doesn't already work as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've got it working with all of the code above now, I believe. Should I take out CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS as well?

Comment: You can, if it's not needed.  `file_get_contents` wasn't posting anything.

Comment: I don't have the cred to upvote, but you definitely helped! Just an fyi: I tried taking out file_get_contents, and it didn't work. I was able to take out CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION